# How do I remove "undefined" from the beginning of JavaScript array items?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate an array of random digits, but I'm getting "undefined" at the beginning of each row. I've been searching online for a couple of hours, but haven't been able to figure it out.

The expected output should be 5 rows of 2 random digits like this:

```
87
57
81
80
02
```

but the actual output looks like this:

```
undefined87
undefined57
undefined81
undefined80
undefined02
```

This is a modified excerpt that produces the result shown above:

```
function NumberSet() {

  // generate all the digits
  this.generate = function() {
    random_digits = [];

    // create 5 rows of 2 random digits
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
      for(z=0; z<2; z++) {
        // use .toString() in order to concatenate digits to 
        // the array without adding them together
        random_digit = Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString();
        random_digits[i] +=random_digit;
      }
    }
    return random_digits;
  }
}
randomnumbers1 = new NumberSet();
mynums = randomnumbers1.generate();
jQuery.each(mynums, function(i, l) {
  // display output in a div#nums
  $('#nums').append(l + '<br>');
});
```

The final version won't be using this method to display the digits. I'm just trying to troubleshoot where the "undefined" is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your variables

```
 random_digits[i] = "";
 for(z=0; z<2; z++) {
    random_digit = Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString();
    random_digits[i] +=random_digit;
  }
```

Declare the variables properly with `var`.

```
var random_digit, random_digits = [];
```

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was missing: `random_digits[i] = "";` I added your other tip as well.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `random_digit` in the first `for` loop and assign an empty string.
Go through the inner `for` loop appending your random numbers, and then `push()` to the array back in the outer `for` loop.

```
function NumberSet() {
  // generate all the digits -a meme should be attached here-
  this.generate = function() {
    random_digits = [];

    // create 5 rows of 2 random digits
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
      var random_digit = ""; //Declare it out here
      for(z=0; z<2; z++) {
        // use .toString() in order to concatenate digits to 
        // the array without adding them together
        random_digit += Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString(); //Append it here
      }
      random_digits.push(random_digit); //Push it back here
    }
    return random_digits;
  }
}
```

[Fiddle-dee-dee](http://jsfiddle.net/LrSNd/)

### OR Forget the inner loop and use recursion

```
function NumberSet() {

    // generate all the digits
    this.generate = function () {
        random_digits = [];

        // create 5 rows of 2 random digits

        // Use i for how many numbers you want returned!
        var random_digit = function (i) {
            var getRand = function() {
                return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString());
            }
            return (i > 0) ? getRand()+random_digit(i-1) : "";
        };

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            random_digits.push(random_digit(2)); //In this case, you want 2 numbers
        }
        return random_digits;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle-do-do](http://jsfiddle.net/LrSNd/1/)

### And the final version because I'm bored

```
function NumberSet(elNum, numLen) {
    this.random_digits = []; //Random digits array
    this.elNum = elNum; //Number of elements to add to the array
    this.numLen = numLen; //Length of each element in the array
    // generate all the digits

    this.generate = function () {
        // create 5 rows of 2 random digits
        var random_digit = function (i) {
            var getRand = function () {
                return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString());
            }
            return (i > 0) ? getRand() + random_digit(i - 1) : "";
        };
        for (i = 0; i < this.elNum; i++) {
            this.random_digits.push(random_digit(this.numLen)); 
        }
        return this.random_digits;
    }
}

randomnumbers1 = new NumberSet(5, 2).generate();

jQuery.each(randomnumbers1, function (i, l) {
    // display output in a div#nums
    $('#nums').append(l + '<br>');
});
```

[Fiddle on the roof](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/LrSNd/2/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that out. I used the fix in the first comment that was at the top of the page, but learned a lot from reading your examples. (I'm still learning JS.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
random_digits[i] +=random_digit;
```

With

```
random_digits[i] = (random_digits[i]  == undefined ? '' : random_digits[i]) + random_digit;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FUZEq/2/)

Comment: The first digit will be lost if it is `0` since it is falsy. You need an explicit check for `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be simplified to:

```
function NumberSet() {

  this.generate = function() {
    var random_digits = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
        random_digits[i] = (randnum < 10 ? '0' : 0) + randnum;
    }
    return random_digits;
  }
}
```

[**<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/GBpvb/)